# How to show error message in iframe while loading different domain url in java script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

Can anybody tell How to show error message in iframe while loading different domain url in java script.We are getting url from server .if it is same domain we can able to load the url,but it is some other domain it is showing blank iframe .can anybody tell how to show error message in iframe

Thanks

Comment: use the `onerror` tag: `<iframe src="example.org" onerror="alert('Could not load');">`

Comment: @MadsMarquart — That won't error cross-origin.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Any means of detecting it would violate the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).